# animating an image in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiwebview

I saw this on flipboard app, where they basically have an image in a UIWebView and then when you tap on the image it brings you to full screen and you can pinch to zoom in/out. My question is basically on how to create an animation like what they have, it seems that they the image on the UIWebView is animated. If you have an app, try to going into your facebook feed via flipboard and touch an image and you'll see what I mean. Here are some screenshots of the first and final view:

[image]
[image]

Usually in a web view those image are stored as links and some downloading needs to be performed to extract that image and add a gesture recognizer to it. How do they do it so fast?

Answer (score 0):

The part of the UI you are talking about (the top with the image) is not a UIWebView. It is there own custom UIView of some sort showing a teaser of the content. The bottom faded out part is a UIWebView of the original article.

I imagine the way the implemented it would be to have a tap gesture recognizer on the image and when the tap occurs animating the scaled down version of the image to the full size of the screen.

The code of handling the tap gesture might look like this (very very simple):

```
-(void)_imageTapOccured:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{
        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, widthOfScreen, heightOfScreen);
    }];
}
```

Then they will also likely handle the tap to change the picture back to the original size:

```
-(void)_imageTapAtFullScreen:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{
        imageView.frame = originalRectSize;
    }];
}
```